SQL query to sum some values from preceeding rows depending on the row values
I managed to get the following table:



from
to
value
id
start_row
end_row




A
B
20
1
NULL
1


C
D
30
2
NULL
2


B
C
100
3
NULL
3


E
A
50
4
NULL
4


A
D
70
5
1
5


C
A
20
6
2
6



For the rows having both START_ROW and END_ROW I would like to sum the values of the preceeding rows based on two conditions: the ID must be between START_ROW and END_ROW and the field FROM or TO must be the same of the FROM field of the row.
So in this case Row ID 5 should sum Value from Rows 1,4 and 5
While Row ID 6 should sum Value from Rows: 2,3,6.
Any ideas?

Is it always the case that you want to sum this and the previous 4 rows?

This is simply a correlated subquery. No reason to make it more complicated:
select id,
    (
    select sum(t2.value) from T t2
    where t2.id between t.start_row and t.end_row
        and t."from" in (t2."from", t2."to")
    ) as v
from T t
where start_row + end_row is not null


Create an anchor table from your in data consisting of the rows where both start_row and end_row are not null; I called it anchor.
Join that anchor intermediate table back with your in data, applying the join conditions as you stated them: id must be smaller or equal to the anchor's id, and fromval (FROM and TO are reserved words and I won't use them as column names) of the obtained anchor must be one of fromval or toval of your in data. Finally, it's just a matter of grouping and summing.
WITH
-- your in data
indata(fromval,toval,value,id,start_row,end_row) AS (
          SELECT 'A','B', 20,1,NULL,1
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','D', 30,2,NULL,2
UNION ALL SELECT 'B','C',100,3,NULL,3
UNION ALL SELECT 'E','A', 50,4,NULL,4
UNION ALL SELECT 'A','D', 70,5,   1,5
UNION ALL SELECT 'C','A', 20,6,   2,6
)
-- real query starts here, replace following comma with "WITH"
,
anchors AS (
  SELECT * FROM indata
  WHERE start_row IS NOT NULL
    AND end_row IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT
  anchors.id        AS id
, SUM(indata.value) AS sumvals
FROM indata
JOIN anchors
  ON indata.id <= anchors.id
 AND anchors.fromval IN (indata.fromval,indata.toval)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
;




id
sumvals




5
140


6
150




I see, better ON indata.id <= anchors.id by change to ON indata.id between anchor.start_row and anchor.end_row

Indeed. Now I'm re-reading your description , it should be a BETWEEN predicate
